# manipulate array by jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the loop below:

```
        var myArray = [];
        $(this).children('a').each(function () {
            myArray.push($(this).attr('href'));
        });
```

which fires 3 times. When I look inside that array, I see that there is only one (last added) item. Why ?

Comment: What is this code inside of? If you're inside another function or loop, you're resetting the myArray each time you get to it.

Comment: Is this the entire code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you use declare `myArray` as a local variable. If you want the array's values to persist, move `var myArray = [];` outside the common function.

```
var myArray = []; // This variable is shared by all instances of somefunction
$('#example').click(function() {
    $(this).children('a').each(function () {
        myArray.push($(this).attr('href'));  //myArray in the parent scope
    });
});
```

Comment: it's declared outside the jquery function, so i don't think this it the problem. + it does has one value...

Comment: @gdoron I don't see all of the code. It's perfectly possible that the OP invokes the function using `.click().click().click()` = 3 triggers. Still, if `var myArray = [];` is inside the click event handler, the array will only be locally available.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using for loops as they are much faster.

http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loop/44

Try this:

```
var myArray = [],
    links = $("a.link");
for (var i = 0, l = links .length; i < l; i++) {
    myArray.push($(links[i]).attr("href"));
}
console.log(myArray);
```